# “concern of ”or “concern about”

Tags: phrases

I want to say

> I'm worrying about something

Which one should I use，either “concern **of** something” or “concern **about** something”？

Thanks for your answering.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to say I'm worrying about something，and which one should I use，either “concern of something” or “concern about something”？

Unfortunately, neither of your suggestions are correct.

You could say:

> I am concerned about something.

or

> I have a concern about something.

or simply:

> I have a concern.
>
> I am concerned.

It is also acceptable to say you have a concern or are concerned *over* something (rather than "about"). Also you may say you are concerned *for* someone or something.

Answer (score 1):

None of them if you want to use the verb **concern**.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[concern](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concern)**

> to cause worry to someone
>   *The state of my father's health concerns **us** greatly.*
>  *[ + that ] It
>   concerns **me** that he hasn't been in contact.*

The subject is that something that you are worried about.

> [Something] is concerning me
>  It concerns me that [whatever]

You can also use the adjective **[concerned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concerned)** in the way that Astralbee has suggested